# counting data with specific attribute in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am pretty new to Haskell, how can I how many data variables there are in list with specific attribute I am getting from the user?
To do the same with attribute I know I did this: (first I filtered the list and then returned its length)

```
cashInBoolian :: Transaction -> Bool 
cashInBoolian (Transaction CashIn _ _) = True
cashInBoolian _ = False 
secMain :: Int -> String
secMain s= show (length (countCahsInTransactions [(Transaction CashIn BTC 50000),(Transaction CashOut BTC 7000),(Transaction CashIn BTC 50000)]))
```

I tried this but it didn't work-

```
countCoinValoum :: Coin -> [Transaction] -> Int
countCoinValoum c tr =length . filter ((Transaction _ c _)==) tr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach

```
countCoinValoum c tr = length . filter (...) tr
```

is quite sensible, but if you're going to use the composition operator you need to compose two *functions*. But `filter` applied to both its predicate and list gives you back a list; you can't compose a list with a function. You could *apply* the function to the list

```
countCoinValoum c tr = length $ filter (...) tr
```

but a nicer alternative is to only apply `filter` *partially* to only its predicate:

```
countCoinValoum c tr = length . filter (...) $ tr
```

[or simply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B7-reduction).

```
countCoinValoum c = length . filter (...)
```

So, for the predicate – `((Transaction _ c _)==)` looks nice, but this doesn't work. You would need to generate the actual value `Transaction _ c _` and feed it to the `==` operator, but that's not a value, only a *pattern*. You *can* use this in a lambda binding though:

```
countCoinValoum c = length . filter (\(Transaction _ c' _) -> c==c')
```

Alternativaly, assuming the data type is

```
data Transaction = Transaction
       { chashIn :: Cash
       , coinFormat :: Coin
       , superfluousInformation :: [Quark]
       }
```

then you can use the *record field accessor* and compose it with the partially applied equality:

```
countCoinValoum c = length . filter ((c==) . coinFormat)
```